# Getting selected filter twice in magento 1.9.3 layered navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have setup Magento 1.9.3 on my server and uploaded all products and categories from admin panel, but when i go to front-end category page and filter products by category/size/color.

But in the result the selected filter shows twice in layered navigation. I have checked layout xml and html but I didn't get why this is happening.

See the attached screenshot:

[image].

Comment: Hi Guys i searched the solutions, it was not Magento bug this was from theme provider team, they wrote "layer_view" block twice in catalog.xml; once in "left" block and second inside "product list" block. this has been solved for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case `layer_view` block was called twice inside`catalog_category_layered` block in catalog.xml layout. I removed one and problem had been resolved.